# How resiliant is Gemfire to collisions and duplicate entries?

Tags: java, gemfire

I'm writing up the design docs for a Java application where two redundant processes read items off a message queue, and we want both of them to store the item to a gemfire store with the same key, the intent is to have a number of applications running continuous queries process these items and then store the results into another Gemfire region.

I'm just getting to grips with Gemfire and I don't have the capacity to setup a multi server test bed at the moment, so I thought I'd ask a few questions while I do my research.

Assuming both processes store the item in gemfire at the same time will this cause any issues?

If a key is written to twice will the item just get overwritten, and am I likely to hit any issues (performance or otherwise) with the key being locked?

If I have a continuous query running that the item would match would I get two "hits"/(Events?) on the query or would just the first one generate a hit?

How would this be different if I had 4 processes writing identical items with identical keys to the store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scenario that you outlined will work fine if the region to which you are writing is partitioned. In this case there will be a lock on the primary key only for as long as it takes to make a copy of the object on a different node. The primary consideration here is the speed of your network. The second write will overwrite the first. As to whether or not this is fine for your performance would depend on how many objects you have streaming in per second.

Here are some alternates to consider:
1) You can create a durable queue and run the CQ on one client only. If the client fails, you just restart it and you still have consistency. 
2) Create a partitioned "transaction" region on the server. On your client, put the object returned from your CQ into the "transaction" region and add the CQ timestamp as a part of the key. In an async event listener for the "transaction" region, update your target region and delete the object in the "transaction" region.
3) Create a "transaction" partitioned region that is co-located with your target region. Create a function onRegion(partitionedTransactionRegion).withFilter(key).withArguments(object and CQ timestamp). Your client calls the function with the above signature. The function checks if the key + timestamp has already been added in the "transaction" region. If so, ignore the operation. If not, set the key (key + CQ timestamp) in the "transaction" region and update your target region. Set an expiration policy on the "transaction" region to expire after an hour, or day, or your preference.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this.